# CodeIgniter nested foreach shows nothing as a result or error

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am building an app with CodeIgniter. I have a situation in which I need to display user submitted images for each trip. images get uploaded, but when its a turn to display them, my foreach won't show anything. Can you please help me cope this situation? here is my view:

```
    <?php
    if(count($photos) > 0) {
    foreach($photos as $photo_strip){ ?>
    <div>
    <span class="title"><?= $photo_strip['trip']->title ?></span>
    <span class="upload" data-id="<?= $photo_strip['trip']->id ?>">Upload Photos</span>
    <div class="image-box">
    <ul>
    <?php

    foreach($photo_strip['photos'] as $photo) { ?>
    <li>

    <img src="<?= $photo->image ?>" alt=""/>

    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="content">
            <div class="no-data">
                No Images Uploaded Yet
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

When I `print_r($trip_section);` it shows me the whole array, but when I do the same `print_r` or `var_dump` inside the second foreach loop, it show nothing, that whole section is blank. Is there anything wrong I am doing? Is there any other way I can do this?
Thank you so much.

here is the var_dump for both arrays: 
$photos:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["trip"]=> object(stdClass)#52 (28) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
["title"]=> string(23) "My Beach Trip" 
["image"]=> string(36) "5D2EEC96513F83C760A4EEF2DFF637CA.jpg" 
["thumbnail"]=> string(36) "A4786CA32EE9D2E3FB05B7A58C577B68.jpg" ["type"]=> string(4) "trip" 
["country"]=> string(1) "1" ["city"]=> string(1) "1" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" 
["featured"]=> string(1) "0" ["venue"]=> string(34) "cleansing" ["description"]=> string(475) "my dicription" 
["vacancy"]=> string(1) "7" ["minimum_attendee"]=> string(1) "2" ["map_link"]=> string(0) "" 
["internal_status"]=> string(1) "2" 
["price"]=> string(3) "105" 
["slug"]=> string(23) "my-trip" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "00:00:00" 
["end_time"]=> string(8) "00:00:00" ["timezone"]=> string(1) "0" 
["trip_date"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
["create_date"]=> string(19) "2015-10-14 04:09:22" ["modify_date"]=> string(19) "2015-10-28 14:32:35" ["supplier_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["cancellation_policy"]=> string(2) "24" ["lat_long"]=> string(30) "(30.160477, 10.20730500000002)" 
["countryName"]=> string(20) "My country" 
["cityName"]=> string(5) "my city" } 
["photos"]=> array(0) { } 
["trip_date"]=> object(stdClass)#53 (5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "23" 
["tid"]=> string(1) "2" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "15:00:00" 
["end_time"]=> string(8) "19:30:00" 
["trip_date"]=> string(19) "2015-10-22 00:00:00" } } } 


array(3) { ["trip"]=> object(stdClass)#52 (28) { 
["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["title"]=> string(23) "My trip" 
["image"]=> string(36) "5D2EEC96513F83C760A4EEF2DFF637CA.jpg" 
["thumbnail"]=> string(36) "A4786CA32EE9D2E3FB05B7A58C577B68.jpg" 
["type"]=> string(4) "tour" ["country"]=> string(1) "1"
["city"]=> string(1) "1" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" 
["featured"]=> string(1) "0" ["venue"]=> string(34) "cleansing" 
["description"]=> string(475) "my description" 
["vacancy"]=> string(1) "7" ["minimum_attendee"]=> string(1) "2" 
["map_link"]=> string(0) "" ["internal_status"]=> string(1) "2" 
["price"]=> string(3) "105" ["slug"]=> string(23) "my-trip" 
["start_time"]=> string(8) "00:00:00" 
["end_time"]=> string(8) "00:00:00" ["timezone"]=> string(1) "0" 
["tour_date"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
["create_date"]=> string(19) "2015-10-14 04:09:22" 
["modify_date"]=> string(19) "2015-10-28 14:32:35" ["supplier_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
["cancellation_policy"]=> string(2) "24" ["lat_long"]=> string(30) "(30.160477, 10.20730500000002)" 
["countryName"]=> string(20) "My country" 
["cityName"]=> string(5) "my city" } 
["photos"]=> array(0) { } ["tour_date"]=> object(stdClass)#53 (5) { 
["id"]=> string(2) "23" ["tid"]=> string(1) "2" 
["start_time"]=> string(8) "15:00:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "19:30:00" 
["trip_date"]=> string(19) "2015-10-22 00:00:00" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this working code sample at http://phpfiddle.org/ to help debug your code.  I suspect your array is not structured how you think.  Withoutseeing the actual `var_dump` for `$photos` or `$photo_strip` I can't really weigh in anymore.  This has nothing to do with Code Igniter.

```
<?php
            $photos = array(array("trip" => (object)array("title"=>"Beach", "id"=>1), "photos" => array((object)array("image"=>"http://placehold.it/350x150"))));
            if(count($photos) > 0) {
            foreach($photos as $photo_strip){ ?>
            <div>
            <span class="title"><?= $photo_strip['trip']->title ?></span>
            <span class="upload" data-id="<?= $photo_strip['trip']->id ?>">Upload Photos</span>
            <div class="image-box">
            <ul>
            <?php

            foreach($photo_strip['photos'] as $photo) { ?>
            <li>

            <img src="<?= $photo->image ?>" alt=""/>

            </li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="content">
                    <div class="no-data">
                        No Images Uploaded Yet
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

---

EDIT:

Ok looking at your `var_dump` note that `["photos"]=> array(0) { }`.  **Your photos array is empty**.  So basically `foreach($photo_strip['photos'] as $photo)` is doing nothing because their are no photos.  This code is working as intended; if you had photos they would be shown.  Your problem is probably back in the controller or model where you add in the photos.  To debug, manually add some photos to the photo array and see if it shows up in your view.  After it does, then figure out how to correctly tie everything.

Comment: Thank you @Murtnowski  I have updated my question and added var_dump for both arrays. Can you please look into it now?

Comment: I see, Thank you so much for this @Murtnowski.